No such element exception in this Java code; what happened?
The code below asks the user how many numbers they have. It ensures that the number they entered is 0 or greater. Then, it asks the user for each of those numbers.  If 13 was entered at least once, prints "13 was here!". Otherwise prints "no 13 was found".
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Question 1");
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you have?: ");
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        while (!(count > 0)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a non-negative integer.");
            System.out.print("How many numbers do you have?: ");
            count = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int num = 0;
        int appearances = 0;
        System.out.print("\nEnter your numbers here...\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i += 1) {
            System.out.print("");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            if (num == 13) {
                appearances += 1;
            }
        }
        if (appearances > 0) {
            System.out.print("\n13 was here!");
        }
        
        
            
    }
    
}

On line 14, the error occurs:
MyProgram.java: Line 14: java.util.NoSuchElementException
What's wrong?
This code should work, yet it doesn't. Even my Java instructor couldn't figure it out.

what was the input? (NoSuchElementException often means the input was closed/terminated)

That code works fine for me. I suspect you may be running a previous version of the code. Make sure you recompile it and try again.

Are you running this from inside an IDE, or in an online compiler? Try running it on the command line. Some environments, such as some IDEs and online compilers, lack a standard input stream.

https://ideone.com/oHD3vY works for me.

@Sören - but it is easy to reproduce the error, same code (fork of yours)  just different input: https://ideone.com/nS3HsT (reason for my comment and k314159's one)

@user85421 So... working as expected?

You can easily provoke this error by pressing ctrl-d (EOF)
